# Meaning of Yang-Baxter equation for classical $r$-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory, integrable-systems

I'm reading this [[math/9802054](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9802054)] paper on the structure of the phase space of Chern-Simons TQFT. I'm stuck at the definition of the classical $r$-matrix, which goes as follows:

[image]

This might sound dumb, but I don't understand what $r_{12}$, $r_{23}$, $r_{13}$, $r_{21}$ is. I could greatly benefit from an illustrating example.

Equation (15) suggests that $r_{12}$ and $r_{21}$ from equation (14) can be defined as $r$ and its transpose. But I suspect that $r_{12}$ from equation (13) is different, and probably has smth to do with higher tensor powers of $\mathfrak{g}$, but I simply couldn't come up with a meaningful definition. This is embarassingly confusing.

Comment: I think you get the classical YB equation by infinitesimal variation of the usual YB equation.

Comment: @RyanThorngren Correct, see also https://mathoverflow.net/q/239079 and its answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A classical [$R$-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-matrix) $r\in \mathfrak{g}\otimes \mathfrak{g}$ is an element of the 2nd tensor power of an algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ (formally extending the algebra with a unit element ${\bf 1}$).

   The notation $r_{k\ell}\in \mathfrak{g}\otimes \mathfrak{g}\otimes \mathfrak{g}$ for an element of the 3rd tensor power means that $r$ belongs to the $k$'th and $\ell$'th copy of the algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and one should plug ${\bf 1}$ into the remaining copy. (If $k>\ell$ this involves a transposition.)
2. The notation for the quantum $R$-matrix
   $$R~=~{\bf 1}\otimes{\bf 1} +\hbar r +{\cal O}(\hbar^2)$$
   and the [quantum Yang-Baxter equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Baxter_equation) is similar.
3. See also the related [Sweedler notation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Sweedler+notation).

Comment: See, this was my original idea. But unless I am missing something (which I probably am), there’s no such element as 1 in the Lie algebra.

Comment: Could you explain what it means to “formally extend a Lie algebra with a unit element”, please?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus It's like when considering central extensions: $\hat{\mathfrak g}=\mathfrak{g}\oplus \mathbb C{\bf 1}$, where ${\bf 1}$ commutes with everything. Right?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I think I get it now, thanks! So basically, we are considering the universal enveloping algebra instead of the Lie algebra itself. And we are using the unit from that enveloping algebra here. Right?

Comment: @JulesLamers your comment doesn’t make a lot of sense to me. Please provide an explicit expression for $r_{13}$ for this case so that I can understand what you mean.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I mean that Qmechanic's explanation of the notation $r_{kl}$ is correct, but just is not called 'Sweedler notation': the latter is something else. In other words, I completely agree with this answer if one removes the word 'Sweedler' (and the link).

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: @Qmechanic It's better but I would still suggest removing your point 3 altogether; it's just not really relevant here. (Sweedler notation can be used for any coalgebra, where it gives a convenient way to work with coproducts of arbitrary elements. It is not related to the existence of an r- (or R-)matrix, and certainly not to the notation with the subscripts from the question.)