# Importance of the Yang-Baxter equation for integrable models

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integrable-systems

The [Yang-Baxter equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Baxter_equation), or rather one given solution of the Yang-Baxter equation corresponding to some model is often described as the fundamental relation defining an integrable model. However in the construction of the transfer matrix of the XXZ spin chain or equivalently of the 6-vertex model, which can be found *e.g.* [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06805) or [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02100), the Yang Baxter equation for the $R$-matrix is deduced as a compatibility condition for two reordering of a product of three monodromy matrices to be equivalent (see for instance (B.39) in [Franchini 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06805)), and is not even a necessary condition for the $RTT$ relation to hold, and thus for the transfer matrix to commute.

Thus, I fail to see, in this elementary example, why is the Yang-Baxter equation (understood as the relation between two products of three $R$ matrices) so fundamental in integrability.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105181/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/402771/226902  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73/226902